# Magnifying circle view on top of UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uikit, magnify

How to achieve the following magnification/loupe/zoom effect over the Horizontal UIScrollView using some circle view on the very top? Basically, I'd like to magnify/zoom everything behind the circle view.

I already tried using [MagnifyingGlass](https://github.com/niczyja/MagnifyingGlass-Swift) library, but seems like it doesn't really fit into the problem.

[image: Instagram Effects Bar]

Comment: Make a screenshot when tapped and use that zoomed image to add a view with a circle mask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AlexanderVolkov You mean a screenshot of the content view of scroll view, right? I could do it, but how to deal with scrolling inside the circle then? I mean how the zoomed image will move inside the circle? Best, Aibek

Comment: It's not. You just need to monitor the coordinate of the finger, then convert it into a related coordinate in [0,1]x[0,1] space (parent view width x height), then convert to the coordinates of the zoomed image (it will have a larger size), then take a piece of that image (or calculate an offset if you will show full zoomed and masked image), then put that image into the circle and render circle at the point of the finger. Simple 2d calculations.

Comment: ..or you need a larger version of the content (no images) and calculate the correct offset for the masked area of the larger version.